# Openstack VM authentication and authorization using SSH

Tags: openstack, openldap

How could we dynamically provide user authentication and authorization for OpenStack Overlay infrastructure using SSH keys?

Details:
- I have a bunch of VMs running on top of OpenStack and I would like to embed ssh keys of all the authorized users to a group of VMs whenever a new VM is spun up. Say: all HR guyz to VMs grouped as HR VMs and Sales guyz to VMs grouped as Sales VMs or Developers to VMs meant for CI/CD
- I want to add or remove ssh keys whenever the user joins or leaves the organisation dynamically.

I thought of using Puppet or Ansible but both these solutions are not dynamic. I have to add a VM to Puppet each time a VM is spun up, similarly add VMs to Ansible Inventory file each time a VM is created or deleted.

Anyone using Production solutions that will help me manage/orchestrate user management in a dynamically scalable environment of VMs (more complex containers)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have used Cloudinit for this kind of thing. Cloudinit allows you to inject many kinds of information into your OS (including ssh keys) the first time your OS is booted.

It can also be used to configure services which is very handy. All configuration will survive OS reboots.

I have used Cloudinit with CoreOS but I can see that it started life in Ubuntu and now there are many more distros that support it.

https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/cloud-config.html
https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Hi, I have come across Cloudinit but that is only during VM creation ... how can I manage adding and removal of SSH keys on a ongoing basis with Cloudinit?